# AngularJS SPA skeleton with logon and nested views

Tags: gratis, open-source, angularjs, user-management, login

The title pretty much says it all. I am looking for a FOSS starter app, a skeleton in AngularJS single page application, which both:

- Supports nested views. I am thinking of having a tabbed interface structure, where each tab can have nested tabs.
- Since I am not so hot on web security, I would like it to have a login dialog and some good, high quality checking to make sure that the user cannot access any part of the app unless he is logged in.

Anything beyond that is a bonus, especially in the way of security, graceful handling of server not available situations, or other standard web app features. I will probably use UI Bootstrap, but can add that myself.

---

[Update] Even a bounty couldn't coax a response to what seems to me to be a fairly standard & widely applicable question. So, I am googling & researching and will post here what I found as help for others who might see this question in the future.

So far, [this looks promising](https://start.spring.io/), as it allows to check a few boxes (such as "security") and then generates a skeleton app.

---

[Update++] The server side, if supplied (which I hope that it will be), should be PHP.

---

[Yet another update] OK, then, I will settle for just the client side.

Does anyone know of any good AngularJS for registering new users, logging in, handling lost passwords, etc.? With user input validation (valid email entered, repeated passwords match, etc.)?

It should have a nice clean Ajax interface, so that I can code the server-side PHP myself.

Comment: Check https://jhipster.github.io/

Comment: "JHipster is a Yeoman generator, used to create a Spring Boot + AngularJS project." - can you confirm that Spring is java? I was looking for PHP/MySql on the server side :-(

Comment: yes spring is Java framework