# RAD JavaScript Single Page Application IDE

Tags: javascript, ide, rad

Since [my previous question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17209/angular-js-spa-skeleton-with-logon-and-nested-views) got no replies, despite a bounty, I am willing to ditch AngularJS, if this question receives a satisfactory answer.

Rather than ask for a skeleton, as would be acceptable for AngularJS, since I know it, I will ask if there is a RAD-style IDE which allows me to visually build JS apps (something like Delphi, MSVC, etc).

- it should be free, even for commercial use
- it should be well supported
- it should allow me to drag & drop "components" (list boxes, combos, check boxes, date pickers & more) to layout my page
- it should help me to generate a skeleton Single Page Application to whcih I need only add the app-specific logic
- the SPA should support multiple nested tabs & the IDE should generate the appropriate code for routing
- MVC with 2-way data-binding is desirable
- report generation would be "nice to have"
- other bells & whistles would be welcome

Comment: I just talked to our in-house JS-guru and she said that there is no such software.

Answer (score 1):

[WaveMaker](https://www.wavemaker.com) is one such IDE/RAD tool to build web and mobile (hybrid) apps visually using drag-and-drop components. It was earlier based on Dojo toolkit but has now been rebuilt using AngularJS.

- generates Single Page Applications (SPA)
- you can drag and drop visual components (widgets, charts, list items etc)
- you can do 2-way data binding for CRUD operations by binding to data sources (db, REST APIs etc)
- backend is based on Spring and Hibernate
- offers a free trial but not entirely free

Hope this helps.